# Is it common practice to specify security policy info in the WSDL?

Tags: web-services, ws-security, spring-ws

Our team is implementing SOAP-based web services using Spring-WS and XWSS.  So far we've been relying on Spring-WS to generate the WSDL from our XSDs.  We're now considering whether to document the security requirements in the WSDL using WS-SecurityPolicy or conveying them in a separate document.  Here are the questions we're pondering:

- What's the norm?  Is it common to put the policy in the WSDL?
- Do many (any?) client generators pick up WS-SecurityPolicy info in the WSDL?
- Spring-WS doesn't support WS-SecurityPolicy when generating the WSDL.  Would switching to Apache CXF help us?

Also, we're aware that REST is gaining popularity but SOAP has been designated by the powers that be.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can still help anybody.

> What's the norm? Is it common to put
>   the policy in the WSDL?

Yes, it's common.

> Do many (any?) client generators pick
>   up WS-SecurityPolicy info in the WSDL?

I don't know about many, I use metro and it does generate clients according the security constrains.

Answer (score 1):

So here's what you can do and it is straightforward:

1) Include cxf-bundle library in your project. If you are using maven, you can do this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.18</version>
</dependency>
```

2) Read [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) how to generate java classes from wsdl.

3) Make sure in the pom file, you point to the correct wsdlLocation for generating the java files from wsdl.

4) Initialize your generated client and inject username and password provided to you. Something like this:

```
final YourService service = new YourService();
final YourStub stub = service.getService();

final Map ctx = ((BindingProvider)stub).getRequestContext();

ctx.put("ws-security.username", userName);
ctx.put("ws-security.password", password);

stub.callYourMethod();
```

PS: Please make sure you have the right libraries, I just used cxf-bundle and nothing else from cxf and it worked! Earlier it was not working as I had individually included libraries from cxf.

Hope that helps!!